# Can we write $B_n(x)-B_n(0)=nx^{n-1}$?

Tags: bernoulli-polynomials

Bernouli polynomials satisfies the relation $B_n(x+1)-B_n(x)=nx^{n-1}$.

Can we write $B_n(x)-B_n(0)=nx^{n-1}$  or  something like $B_{n+1}(x)-B_n(0)$ to be equal to $nx^{n-1}$?

I mean I want to change the subscripts to be $B_{n+1}$ and $B_n$ instead of keeping both subscripts to be $B_n$.

Comment: No, $B_n(x)$ is certainly not a constant plus $nx^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, $B_2(x) = x^2 - x - 1/6$, so $B_2(x) - B_2(0) = x^2 - x \neq 2x$.

Maybe you're looking for something like this:
$$\sum_{i=0}^x i^n = \frac{B_{n+1}(x+1) - B_{n+1}(0)}{n+1}.$$

Comment: Can you check the updated question?

Comment: Sure, I'll take a look

Comment: Do you really intend to ask about something of the form f(x) - g(0)? If you take a polynomial with many nonzero coefficients, like $B_{n+1}(x)$ and subtract a constant, it will still have many nonzero coefficients.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include something that may be similar to what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks but I was looking something like $B_m(x)-B_n(0)=f(x^n)$, where $m, \ n$ are different positive integers

Comment: Maybe there is something like that, but I don't know of it. Good luck!

Comment: ok, many thanks for your help